# BLE Advertising Data Stops Working After Some Time (Overflow?)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a device that transmits advertising data regarding car speed, rpm, etc (Can not be connected to). My Android app reads in that data every 10 seconds or so. The app will need to always be reading the data, even in the background. It works fine for about an hour or so but then stops working. The ScanCallback method stops getting called including onScanResult and onScanFailed.

The method that starts the scan:

```
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build();
    scanner.startScan(null, settings, callback);
```

ScanCallback:

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        //Update the UI with the latest info
        final BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = result.getDevice();
        final ScanRecord record = result.getScanRecord();

        if(remoteDevice.getName() == null){
            return;
        }
        else if(!remoteDevice.getName().equals("BT-ext")){
            return;
        }


        //Post scan update to the UI thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateScanResult(record);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error scanning devices: "+errorCode);
    }
};
```

updateScanResult will do some ui work, stop the ble scanning, and then restart it again. I figured the bluetooth was getting overflowed so that's why I restarted the scanning. However, it didn't make any difference.

I've tested this on a Pixel 3 and Samsung S9 and they both stop working after a while. I'm aware of the Bluetooth changes that took place with Android 7.0 but I don't think those restrictions apply here. The bluetooth isn't running for more than 30 minutes because it's being reset.